# second largest from a list prolog

Tags: list, prolog, max

i'm writing a function that returns true if E is the second largest element from the list, especially trying to use the library https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=lists

like this:

```
secLarg([], E).
secLarg([_], E).
secLarg([T], E) :- L is max_member(T, E), delete(T, L), max_member(E, L).
```

so using some sort of composition of library functions max_member and delete, however this solution is not working, as max_member appears to return only true/false, not what the specific largest element is. do you have any idea about how could I find if E is the second largest element by any way using these functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `L is max_member(T, E)` does not make much sense. A predicate does not *return* a value: it either succeeds or fails. It uses *unification* to unify a variable with the result.

If you use `[T]` to unify with, you will only unify with lists with *exactly* one element. Whereas you probably want to unify with lists with an arbitrary number of elements.

`delete/3` also does *not* alter the list, it produces a new list where it removed the largest member:

```
secLarg(Xs, E) :-
    max_member(Lg, Xs),
    delete(Xs, Lg, Xs1),
    max_member(E, Xs1).
```

It also does not make much sense to write `secLarg([], E)` and `secLarg([_], E)`, since for such lists, there is no second largest:

```
% secLarg([], E).
% secLarg([_], E).
secLarg(Xs, E) :-
    max_member(Lg, Xs),
    delete(Xs, Lg, Xs1),
    max_member(E, Xs1).
```

Beware that `delete/3` will delete *all* elements with the given value. Indeed:

```
?- delete([1,4,2,5,4], 4, R).
R = [1, 2, 5].
```

So if there is a list where the largest value occurs multiple times, it will not select the largest value (which is also the second largest one).